# How to calculate a sales price with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to start making calculations with rails, but I do not know where to start.

suppose I want to take as input from the user the following variables. The user sends in a request by filling in a form and the request contains the following variables:

`Cost price = 50
Mark up = 0.5
Container costs = 5000 dollar
Boxes = 25`

And I need to calculate the sales price as follows:

`Sales price = cost price* (1+ Mark up) + Container costs/Boxes`

And I need to put the Sales price on the screen.

Question: How do I make a method to calculate this sales price? And how do I show the sales price on the screen after the user submits the form with all the variables?

There could be 500 requests sent in and my job is to calculate the sales price for each request and show it on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really about ruby so I would start learning more about that.  [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/ruby) is a good place to start.

A basic method for this could be as follows:

```
def calculate_price(price, markup, overhead, boxes)
  (price * (1 + markup)) + (overhead/boxes)
end
```

or, a bit more readable:

```
def calculate_price(price, markup, overhead, boxes)
  base_price = price * (1 + markup)
  packaging  = overhead / boxes

  base_price + packaging
end
```

Comment: Thanks. the one with @sales_price will help me put the information on the screen. I will make an order model and define this calculated_price method in it. There are more complex calculations involved so I need to use a method of the order. Most tutorials don't teach you calculations. I will look at ruby and code academy. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would represent the different real life entities involved as "models" with a corresponding table in your database.  You make a controller which the form submits to.  This takes data from `params` and does stuff with it, possibly using instances of your model classes.

As a totally trivial, and not very nice, example, not using any models, you can just set a variable like this, in your controller method:

```
@sales_price = params[:cost_price].to_f * (1 + params[:mark_up].to_f) + params[:container_costs].to_f/params[:boxes].to_f
```

Then, in the view rendered by this controller action, you can do this:

```
<p>Sales Price: <%= @sales_price %></p>
```

However, this is very fragile, and clunky.  What's more likely is that you would build a model representing an order, or something, which has fields called "boxes" etc, and other models to hold products, and their price, etc, and then build a new Order object from params, which set product_id, etc.